# Compile warning using Opencv in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, syntax

Dear community recently I've been studying a little bit of Opencv and I found interesting the eye tracking stuff, so i found a source code for getting started, but when i tried to compile it I got this warning:

ojos2.cpp:15:5: warning: first argument of ‘int main(int*, char**)’ should be ‘int’ [-Wmain]

well to be more clear I'm compiling from the Ubuntu terminal, and here is the code

```
#include "cv.h"

#include"highgui.h"

IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* img)
{

IplImage *imgHSV=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,3);
cvCvtColor(img,imgHSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
IplImage *imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,1);
cvInRangeS(imgHSV,cvScalar(0, 84, 0, 0),cvScalar(179, 256, 11, 0),imgThresh);
cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
return imgThresh;
}

int main(int *argv,char **argc)
{

IplImage *imgScribble= NULL;
char c=0;
CvCapture *capture;
capture=cvCreateFileCapture("main.avi");

if(!capture)
{
    printf("Camera could not be initialized");
    exit(0);
}
cvNamedWindow("Simple");
cvNamedWindow("Thresholded");

while(c!=32)
{
    IplImage *img=0;
    img=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!img)
        break;
    if(imgScribble==NULL)
        imgScribble=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,3);

    IplImage *timg=GetThresholdedImage(img);
    CvMoments *moments=(CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
    cvMoments(timg,moments,1);

    double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
    double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
    double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);

    static int posX = 0;
    static int posY = 0;

    int lastX = posX;
    int lastY = posY;

    posX = moment10/area;
    posY = moment01/area;
     // Print it out for debugging purposes
    printf("position (%d,%d)\n", posX, posY);
    // We want to draw a line only if its a valid position
    if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0)
    {
        // Draw a yellow line from the previous point to the current point
        cvLine(imgScribble, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), cvScalar(0,255,255), 5);
    }
    // Add the scribbling image and the frame...

    cvAdd(img, imgScribble, img);

    cvShowImage("Simple",img);
    cvShowImage("Thresholded",timg);
    c=cvWaitKey(3);
    cvReleaseImage(&timg);
    delete moments;

}
//cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvDestroyWindow("Simple");
cvDestroyWindow("Thresholded");
}
```

Any help will be useful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the warning message again, it's saying _exactly_ what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype should be `int main (int argv, char *argc[])`, it is the pointer to `argv` that is primarily wrong -- `char **argc` and `char *argc[]` are two ways of saying the same thing, but it is more clear to write it as a pointer to a character array rather than as a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

int main(int argv,char **argc)
Warning is gone.